# converting streams to blocks of strings and vice-versa

Tags: java, scala, xmpp, inputstream, outputstream

I have developed a java/scala XMPP client app that sends data asynchronously using (say) a `write` method and receives data using a `listener` method. The `listener` method receives data as discrete XMPP message packets and processes them using a `processPacket` method (which I can modify based on what I want to do with the received data)

I want to hook up a 3rd party library that reads data from an `inputstream` and writes to an `outputstream`. Specifically, I want the `inputstream` of the 3rd party library to be emulated using the data received via my `listener` method and the `outputstream` to be emulated by my `write` method.

What would be the easiest way to do this? I know that this requires conversion from a stream to chunks of strings and vice-versa. Some hints would be appreciated.

The XMPP message packet structure is as follows (though this can be changed if needed):

```
<message to = ... from = ...><body>data</body></message>
```

Comment: Have you looked at Scala IO? http://jesseeichar.github.com/scala-io/

Comment: Not yet. But, I'll do it now. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ByteArrayInputStream` to create an input stream for a given String. You have to think about encoding, because your sending bytes instead of characters.

```
String text = message.getBody();  // that's what you need?
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

For the other way round, you write to an `ByteArrayOutputStream` and create a new String from it's bytes:

```
String text = new String( baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8" );
```

Again - don't forget to think about character encoding.

Comment: The issue is that the streams are continuous, while the message packets are discrete so I have to consider fragmentation and reassembly before making the stream. Furthermore, I want to process the data as soon as it is received, rather than waiting for the stream to end. (The stream can be several megabytes, packet size limit is approx 2000 bytes.)